# How to bind pebbles in-between pavers?

Tags: concrete, patio, backyard, gravel

I have roughly 700 square feet of pebbles and pavers in my back yard, and the issue I'm having is that when I step on the pebbles, they move all over the place. I'd like to apply some kind of binding that will lock them in place.

Does anyone have any methods or products they'd recommend to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: You can try polymeric sand.  The usual application is for small gaps between pavers, but it might be worth a shot for this.

Comment: @mbeckish, I want to keep the look of the pebbles and not add a sandy texture.

Comment: I know I posted an answer, but note that "product recommendation" questions are considered off-topic for the site.  Product or service recommendations tend to become outdated quickly so they are unlikely to be of much value in the future.

Comment: You should have done a small sample test before going on such a big scale. Build a box with wood, put a tile inside and place the pebbles around it. And stepped on the tile. The issue are your pebbles. I think mbackish has your solution. maybe find a dark sand to fill the gaps.

Comment: This is why concrete was invented. There's nothing practical or reasonably priced that's going to hold a slippery medium in place under concentrated loads. You probably should've poured an exposed-aggregate slab. I admit that your design is attractive, though.

Answer (score 1):

Gravel-lok is the product. It joins the pebbles without creating wierd color films or sandy debris. There is a spray on kind, but the can is a mixture you fold in like dough. The pavers would then be placed atop and a rubber mallet tapping would secure then let cure et voila wet look shiny perma pebbles.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I have never used this product, and haven't really read that much about it, but its something that I came across recently while searching for a different mulch-related product.

http://www.mulchlock.com/

This is a "landscape adhesive" that you can spray on mulch or pebbles that acts like a glue to stick everything together.  There's probably other brands - this is just the one I came across.

Again, I'm not saying this will work, or that it's a good product.  It's just something for you to research.

Comment: I'd surmise that that product isn't intended for foot traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Crushed granite is stable to walk on. It slightly interlocks with itself. I have a path with it similar to the image link below.

[Crushed granite path example](http://www.bristolurnu.org/wp_content/gr/gravel-patio-designs-lovely-exterior-design-awesome-stone-pathway_patio-backyard.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need Fast Patch's resin (see - https://www.pavepatch.com/fastpatch-resin-bulk-c-22.html ). I used their asphalt repair almost 20-years ago and it's still fully intact at the daily use parking spot I did.

My patch was put on nothing but tamped gravel and every kind of vehicle has driven and parked on it. Asphalt sealers, oil drips, sun, rain, snow, ice and salt year after year hasn't killed it yet. The surrounding asphalt's still good too, but I'll be interested to see which goes first.

Answer (score 0):

Ever try epoxy for these pebbles ? Not certain if drainage is intended though

https://www.aeromarineproducts.com/product-category/epoxy/